# CSS Animation: Making elements moving from right to left

Tags: css

There are some elements inside the div `#container` and I wanna animate the elements where they will move to the left from right, but I don't know why it's not working...

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.items {
  height: 210px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: moving 30s infinite linear;
  @keyframes moving {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -900px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of using `background-position` use `transform: translate()`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()).
2. You wrote the `@keyframes` inside the `.item` which is not correct.

```css
  #container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.items {
  height: 210px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: moving 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-450px, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-900px, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I know why it's not infinite? Because it'll be lagging a while when it reaches the end

Comment: I mean when it reaches the last element, it go back to the first element instead of showing the first element after the last element

Comment: What about now?

Comment: It's better but it's not the ideal resultI wanna the first element to show after the last element and moving to the left from right infinity

Comment: Or is this can't be achieved by CSS instead of JavaScript?

Comment: It's okay, I'll open a new question since your answer already solve the problem in question

Comment: I edited the code. if you want to achieve this, yes you need JS and you can also use overflow.